# User entry of date on web page

Tags: date

I have a webpage which uses today’s day (today = new Date();) to take actions according to the date. I want to be able to test it will work on various future dates so I want to be able to have the ability to do user entry on the web page of any date which will be set to equal today and show the webpage as it would be on that new date. How do I user enter a date on the web page which can be set to equal the today variable and then cause the webpage to refresh to the new date?

Answer (score 0):

This is how I did it. On one web page I put the javascript code

```
var fred = new Date(2024,2,10,10,30)
localStorage.setItem("lastname", fred);
```

Then on all other web pages where you want to test the date put

```
var bob = localStorage.getItem("lastname"); 
today = new Date(bob);
```

You enter a test date as fred on the first page and it will pick it up on all other pages.